# Terraform not passing variable to module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to pass a variable from an environment dir to a module, but having some issues. My directory structure looks like this

```
repository
 -> prod
 -> test
      main.tf 
      terraform.tf
      vars.tfvars
 -> modules
     infra
       main.tf
       terraform.tf
```

In test/main.tf I have

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-1"
}

module "launch" {
  source = "../../modules/infra"
  range = var.range
}
```

test/terraform.tf looks like this

```
variable "range" {}
```

test/vars.tfvars

```
range="10.0.0.0/16"
```

modules/infra/main.tf

```
resource "aws_vpc" "testvpc" {
  cidr_block = var.range
}
```

When I run this I get the prompt

```
var.range
  Enter a value:
```

I'm expecting it to pick up the value from the variable automatically, but even when I do enter the value I get the error

```
│ Error: Unsupported argument
on main.tf line 20, in module "launch":
range = var.range 
An argument named "range" is not expected here
```

Is it possible to pass a variable from a file for a given environment to a module?

Comment: what is in `modules/infra/terraform.tf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the file `modules/infra/terraform.tf` contains the variable:

```
variable "range" {}
```

Comment: Thanks! That helps get the plan working. It still prompts for what the variable actually is, any way of handling it dynamically from the test/ dir vars?

Comment: Had it in vars.tfvars rather than terraform.tf, thanks for the help!

Comment: you should have the actual value for range (`range="10.0.0.0/16"`) in `vars.tfvars` but you need to specify the input file in the terraform command: `terraform plan -var-file="vars.tfvars"` unless you name the file `terraform.tfvars` which is what it picks up by default.